# How do you initialize matSortDirection?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am working through an example in an ASP.Net Core 6 and Angular 13 book on Material Tables, paging, sorting and filtering.

The material table in my angular component html looks like this:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="cities"
   class="mat-elevation-z8"
   [hidden]="!cities"
   matSort (matSortChange)="loadData()"
   [matSortActive]="defaultSortColumn"
   [matSortDirection]="defaultSortOrder">
```

And in the component ts file or the controller, it has defaultSortOrder initialized like this:

```
public defaultSortOrder: "asc" | "desc" = "asc";
```

I don't understand this syntax.
I read it as:
"asc" OR "desc" is assigned "asc".

It seems to work but I don't understand what is going on here.
If I try to initialize it to just "asc",

```
public defaultSortOrder = "asc";
```

it says:
"Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SortDirection'."

I tried to read the documentation but I still don't get it.

What does this syntax mean?

```
public defaultSortOrder: "asc" | "desc" = "asc";
```

Answer (score 1):

The code `"asc" | "desc"` is simply declaring the type for `defaultSortOrder`.  It is specifying a union of [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) types, which just means the type is a string of either `'asc'` or `'desc'`.

The code  `= "asc";` is simply assigning the initial value to `defaultSortOrder`.

The reason you receive an error when you omit the type is because Typescript infers the type from the assigned value as any `string` but the component requires a narrower type of a string with values`'asc' | 'desc'`.

So instead of reading as

> "asc" OR "desc" is assigned "asc".

Read as:

> A variable allowed to have the values "asc" or "desc" is assigned "asc"

Comment: Oh I get it now.  That clears it up.  I'm new to TypeScript although I don't know if I should think of it as a TypeScript thing.  I see  now. The type comes after the colon I knew that.

Answer (score 0):

The type can be either of the two values. If you set the value as `'test'` you will get a type error.

```
this.defaultSortOrder = "test"; // <- type error!
```

So we can use this method of defining, when you want the property to have only certain values, in this case `asc` or `desc`!